# Android - Get a ScreenShot of the visible area of a Scrollview

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

How to get a Screen Shot of the visible area of a ScrollView in Android ?

My view hierarchy is as below:
Scrollview - Linear layout - Imageview

Comment: do you want only visible area or complete scroll view include with child's ?

Comment: yes, there is a scrollable image view in my scroll view and i want only part of visible area of that imageview means scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I use in a Utility Class of mine:

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
protected final static boolean shoot
(final Context ctx, final View v, final String appName)
{
    boolean isOK = false;

    // Get the bitmap from the view
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    final Bitmap bmp = v.getDrawingCache();

    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd@HHmmss");
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Set file properties
    fileJPG = appName + "_" + sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    /*
    Create a path where we will place our picture in the user's public
    pictures directory. Note that you should be careful about what you
    place here, since the user often manages these files.
    For pictures and other media owned by the application, consider
    Context.getExternalMediaDir().
    */
    final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
        (
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            //Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/yourAppName/"
        );

    // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
    if(!path.exists())
    {
        path.mkdirs();
    }

    final File file = new File(path, fileJPG + ".jpg");

    try
    {
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 8192);

        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);

        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        fileJPG = file.getPath();
        isOK = true;
    }
    catch (final IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isOK;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I use that, actually. I hope the code is clear enough - I try to keep my code well commented, for future re-use.